# Extra _layouts/15/start.aspx#// in adress bar on even clicks

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation

I have SharePoint 2013 Foundation site that can be accessed through internet.

**When I access from internet (via IP using Forms Auth or Claims Based Auth):**

I click "Documents" (from Quick Navigation panel) for the first time and it redirects me to `http://IP/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. And everything seems ok.

For the second time though it gets me to `http://IP/_layouts/15/start.aspx#//Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. As a result nothing is shown but blank contents.

If I click "Documents" again then the link is again `http://IP/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`.

Etc...
So on even times I get extra `_layouts/15/start.aspx#//`. And it isn't related only to "Documents", but pretty much of functionality works that way.

**When I access from the server machine (via Machine name using Windows Auth):**

When I click "Documents" the address is always `http://machinename/_layouts/15/start.aspx#/Shared%20Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx`. And everything work as expected.

Does anybody have ideas what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is Minimal Download Strategy (MDS) feature at work.  Its purpose is to improve performance by minimizing what the browser has to download as a user navigates pages.

You may want to re-test the behaviors you describe after you disable the MDS feature on your site.  You can do this by going to the **Site Settings** > **Manage site features** and then deactivate the **Minimal Download Strategy** feature.

Comment: Thank you! I changed it and restarted IIS. And it worked. But I believe MDS should work for my scenario. Can you think of anything else that gives me such a behavior when i have MDS enabled?